# What method in Eloquent or Query Builder in Laravel 5.2 for unique values

Tags: controller, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Here is the scenario

Table: Users

`id     | name  | grade
------  | ------|------
   1    | Mark  |   a
   2    | Earl  |   a
   3    | John  |   c
   4    | Mike  |   d
   5    | Matt  |   e`

What I want to do is populate the grades that are non-repeating or non-duplicate grades

So it should just show

c
d
e

---

I've got this far

controller
`$grades = user::select('grade')
        ->distinct()
        ->get();`

blade
`@foreach ($grades as $grade)
            {{ $grade }}<br>
            @endforeach<br><br>`

however, this query gives this

a
c
d
e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:-

```
$grades = DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT grade , count(grade) as gradecount  FROM users  group 
by grade having gradecount = 1'));

                    OR

$grades = DB::table('users')
            ->select('*', DB::raw('COUNT(grade) as gradecount'))
            ->groupBy('grade')
            ->having('gradecount', '=',1)
            ->get();
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes thanks s lot! I will be posting another question. Will put link here

Comment: here is another question I wish you can answer   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43905484/how-to-use-conditional-for-this-query-in-laravel-5-2#comment74844746_43905484