# How to use conditional for this query in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, controller, laravel-5

Here is the scenario

Table: Users

```
id   | name  | grade  | subject
---- | ------|--------|------
1    | Mark  |   a    |   science
2    | Earl  |   a    |   english
3    | John  |   c    |   english
4    | Mike  |   d    |   science
5    | Matt  |   e    |   english
```

What I want to do is populate the grades that are non-repeating or non-duplicate grades but for english subject only

So it should just show

```
c
e
```

---

I've got this far

controller:

```
$grades = user::select('grade', DB::raw('COUNT(grade) as gradecount'))
->where('subject', 'english')
->groupBy('grade')
->having('gradecount', '=',1)
->get();
```

blade:

```
@foreach ($grades as $grade)
            {{ $grade }}
            @endforeach
```

However, this query gives this

```
a
c
e
```

Comment: try using where clauses, https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#where-clauses

Comment: where('subject', '=', 'english')->get()

Comment: thanks manian, however, the problem is 'a' is still there. 'a' should be in the list. I want FIRST to get all with gradecount = 1, then after that, those that has subject = english

Comment: This query fetched exactly what you expected. I tested it in my laravel instance. $grades = User::select('grade', \DB::raw('COUNT(grade) as gradecount'))
     ->where('subject', 'english')
     ->groupBy('grade')
     ->having('gradecount', 1)
     ->get();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to do something like this:

```
SELECT grade
FROM Users
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id 
    FROM Users
    GROUP BY grade
    HAVING COUNT( grade ) = 1
) AND subject = 'english'`
```

Query builder has a ->whereIn that you should be able to use. Too lazy to test, but something like this may work.

```
$ids = user::select('id')
->groupBy('grade')
->having('gradecount', '=',1)
->get();

$grades = user::select('grade')
->whereIn('id', $ids)
->where('subject', 'english')
->get();
```

Comment: Hi @Jessica Legner, welcome to stack overflow! Let me try those :). I can only use the query builder (your second code) since this is in the controller. But is there a way I can use them as well, your first one?

Comment: it's not pulling up anything. Did I miss something in there?

Comment: Do you get the Id's of the items you desire as a result in the first block ($ids)?  If so, you'll want to make sure you're passing the whereIn the array of the ids. I am skeptical about 'gradecount'.  I don't think that is how it works. Try ->havingRaw('COUNT(grade) = 1').

Also, you can do raw expressions in 5.2: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#where-clauses
The 5.4 docs have a bit of info too: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#raw-expressions

Comment: Hmm.. I appreciate that. Trying that now :)